# Find a string in a string with special pattern C#

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a long string in C# and i need to find substrings that look like this:

```
number.number:number
```

For example this string:

```
text text
965.435:001 text text sample
7854.66:006 text text
```

I want to find and save 965.435:001 and 7854.66:006 to a string somehow.

Comment: The regex you need is `\d+\.\d+:\d+`.

Comment: Thanks, could you provide an code example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- `\d` means "digit"
- `+` means "one or more"
- `\.` means a literal dot (`.` alone would mean "any character")
- `\b` means "word boundary" (start or end of an alphanumeric "word").

So, your regex would be

```
\b\d+\.\d+:\d+\b
```

In C#:

```
MatchCollection allMatchResults = null;
Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"\b\d+\.\d+:\d+\b");
allMatchResults = regexObj.Matches(subjectString);
if (allMatchResults.Count > 0) {
    // Access individual matches using allMatchResults.Item[]
} else {
    // Match attempt failed
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the below in an example how to use regex to find certain formats within a string

```
class TestRegularExpressionValidation
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string[] numbers = 
        {
            "123-456-7890", 
            "444-234-22450", 
            "690-203-6578", 
            "146-893-232",
            "146-839-2322",
            "4007-295-1111", 
            "407-295-1111", 
            "407-2-5555", 
        };

        string sPattern = "^\\d{3}-\\d{3}-\\d{4}$";

        foreach (string s in numbers)
        {
            System.Console.Write("{0,14}", s);

            if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(s, sPattern))
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(" - valid");
            }
            else
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(" - invalid");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use a regex and capture the thing..

play with this code... it should get you what you want...

```
 string text = "your text";
      string pat = @"(\d*\.\d*:\d*)";

      // Instantiate the regular expression object.
      Regex r = new Regex(pat, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

      // Match the regular expression pattern against a text string.
      Match m = r.Match(text);
      int matchCount = 0;
      while (m.Success) 
      {
         Console.WriteLine("Match"+ (++matchCount));
         for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) 
         {
            Group g = m.Groups[i];
            Console.WriteLine("Group"+i+"='" + g + "'");
            CaptureCollection cc = g.Captures;
            for (int j = 0; j < cc.Count; j++) 
            {
               Capture c = cc[j];
               System.Console.WriteLine("Capture"+j+"='" + c + "', Position="+c.Index);
            }
         }
         m = m.NextMatch();
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
var match = Regex.Match("\d+\.\d+:\d+")
while (match.Success){
    numbersList.Add(match.Groups[0])
    match = match.NextMatch()
}
```